# How to evaluate single integrals of multivariate functions with Python's scipy.integrate.quad?

Tags: python, scipy

There is a function I am trying to integrate in Python using `scipy.integrate.quad`.  This particular function takes two arguments.  There is only one argument I want to integrate over.  An example is shown below.

```
from scipy import integrate as integrate
def f(x,a):  #a is a parameter, x is the variable I want to integrate over
    return a*x

result = integrate.quad(f,0,1)
```

This example doesn't work (as is likely clear to you) since, as Python reminds me when I try it:

```
TypeError: f() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I am wondering how to use `integrate.quad()` to integrate in a single variable sense when the function given is, in general, a multi-variable function, with the extra variables providing parameters to the function.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found the answer in [the scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html).

You can do the following:

```
from scipy import integrate
def f(x,a):  #a is a parameter, x is the variable I want to integrate over
    return a*x

result = integrate.quad(f,0,1,args=(1,))
```

The `args=(1,)` argument in the `quad` method will make `a=1` for the integral evalution.

This can also be carried to functions with more than two variables:

```
from scipy import integrate
def f(x,a,b,c):  #a is a parameter, x is the variable I want to integrate over
    return a*x + b + c

result = integrate.quad(f,0,1,args=(1,2,3))
```

This will make `a=1, b=2, c=3` for the integral evaluation.

The important thing to remember for the function you want to integrate this way is to make the variable you want to integrate over the *first* argument to the function.

Comment: `args=(1)` is the same as `args=1`; i.e. without a trailing comma to force the expression to be a tuple, those parentheses don't do anything useful.  According to the `quad` docstring, `args` is expected to be a tuple, but it appears to handle a single value.  To make `args` a tuple of length 1, use `args=(1,)`.

Comment: Would you say the "most correct" way to pass a single argument to `args` is a tuple `args=(1,)`, based on the documentation?

Comment: Based on the documentation, yes.  However, if you check the source code, you'll find that if `args` is not a tuple, the code does `args = (args,)`, so I guess it is "safe" to use `args=1` because of this undocumented feature.  (Note that this means you can't use any sequence other than a tuple to hold multiple arguments.  For example, for your second `f` with four arguments, you can't use `args=[1, 2, 3]`, because internally it will be treated as `([1, 2, 3],)`.)

Comment: And what will happen if we integrate a product of two functions, one say `f(x,a,b)` and the other `g(x,c)`. How would args work in this case?

Comment: What if I have a function `f(x,y,z)` and that the one I need to integrate over a range for `x` and another time over a range of `y`. is this not possible because I can only integrate over the first argument?

Comment: How did `integrate.quad` know that it should pass value 1 to `a` instead of `x`?

Comment: Alternative is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69475268/how-to-run-the-same-integral-for-different-values-of-constants/69475374#69475374

Answer (score 10):

Use the `args` argument (see the [scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html)):

```
result = integrate.quad(f,0,1, args=(a,))
```

The comma in `args=(a,)` is required because a tuple must be passed.

Comment: I got it to work without including the comma.  Which seems strange.  But work it did.

Comment: Yup: the source includes the lines: `if not isinstance(args, tuple):
args = (args,)`, so a single value is fine. If it's not documented, there's no guarantee it won't change in future, though...