# Use scipy.integrate to get integral over a partial set of variables

Tags: python, scipy

I have a function,

```
f = lambda a,b,c,d: <some equation of a,b,c,d>
```

I want to integrate f from a = 0 to 1, and b = 0 to 2 such that I get a function in c and d. How can I do this with scipy.integrate ?

Example -

```
>>> f = lambda a,b,c,d: a+b+c+d
>>> def g(*args):
        f = <some scipy code>
        return f
# After integration lets say we get a function g(c,d)
# We know g(c,d) would be equal to, 2c+2d+3 for the case discussed above. 
# Now this should give,
>>> g(1,1)
7
```

How to implement such code?

Edit: I know that dblquad can be used for two variables, but what to do if there are more than two variables? Say, we had to integrate f(a,b,c,d,e) for a = 0 to 1, b = 0 to 2 and c = -1 to 1 such that it gives a function say, g(d,e).
Edit 2: How should this be done for say, n variables?

Comment: The example in your edit can solved with `tplquad`. Are you looking for an answer that works with any number of variable ?

Comment: Yes. For any number of variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099892/how-to-evaluate-single-integrals-of-multivariate-functions-with-pythons-scipy-i), just use `dblquad` in place of `quad`. If you want a function of `c` and `d` use the `args` argument of `dblquad`:

```
def g(c,d):
    return scipy.integrate.dblquad(f, 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 2, args=(c,d))
```

Comment: Actually, I did go through the thread but this gives a solution only for one or two variables what if the number of variables I want to integrate is more than 2?

Comment: To integrate over more than two variables, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071704/integrating-a-multidimensional-integral-in-scipy

Answer (score 1):

Numeric integeation only works if the function returns a number. Therefore, you either define a function of c and d which inegrates on each invocation, or tabulate this functipn on a grid of c and d and interpolate.

Comment: It would be great if you can elaborate your answer. And can you please tell me what do you mean by "Numeric integeation only works if the function returns a number." ? I mean in the context of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here I propose a solution which implements fixed Gauss-Legendre quadrature for any number of parameters through a class. You create an instance of the class with a function and parameters: a string for a normal parameter, and a list of 2 numbers if you want to integrate over this variable. Then the `__init__` function computes a meshgrid of points on which to evaluate the function. You can choose the number of point in your quadrature.

To use the function, you call the `eval` method which computes the result from the parameters you give.

```
from numpy.polynomial.legendre import leggauss
class Partial_Integrated_Function:
    def __init__(self,f,*args):
        self.f=f
        self.nargs=0 # number of real arguments needed by the function
        self.nintegs=0 # number of vars to integrate
        self.n=10 # quadrature points number
        self.lg_pts,self.lg_wgt=leggauss(self.n)
        self.lg_wgt=self.lg_wgt/2 # for sum=1
        self.eval_pts=[[]] # list of points to evaluate
        self.eval_wgt=[1] # list of weights
        for arg in args:
            if type(arg)==str: # string argument: keep it as a mandatory argument
                self.nargs+=1
                for i in range(len(self.eval_pts)): # add its symbol for each point to evaluate
                    self.eval_pts[i]=self.eval_pts[i]+[arg]
            if isinstance(arg,(list,tuple)) and len(arg)==2: # list argument: integration needed
                self.nintegs+=1
                i=0
                while i<len(self.eval_pts): # for all points
                    l=self.eval_pts.pop(i) # remove the list of values
                    w=self.eval_wgt.pop(i) # remove the weight
                    a,b=arg # integration will go from a to b
                    for j in range(self.n):  # for each quadrature point
                        self.eval_pts.insert(i,l+[(a+b)/2+(b-a)/2*self.lg_pts[j]]) # add the quadrature point to evaluate
                        self.eval_wgt.insert(i,w*self.lg_wgt[j]) # multiply weight by its weight
                    i+=self.n


    def eval(self,*args):
        sum=0
        print("eval",args)
        for i in range(len(self.eval_pts)):
            pt=self.eval_pts[i].copy() # get the point
            w=self.eval_wgt[i]
            j=0 # current arg to use
            for k in range(len(pt)): 
                if type(pt[k])==str: # if we find a string
                    pt[k]=args[j] # we replace it by its value
                    j+=1
            sum+=self.f(*pt)*w 
        return sum

f=Partial_Integrated_Function(lambda x,y,z,t:x+2*y+3*z+4*t,"x",[2,3],[0,1],"t") 
# the function is x,t |-> int_y=2^3 ( int_z=0^1 x+2*y+3*z+4*t dz ) dy
# so f(x,t)=x+4*t+6.5
print(f.eval(0,0))
print(f.eval(1,0))
print(f.eval(0,1))
```

Comment: This seems useful. Is it sure there are no libraries that already provide this functionality? If not, this can be worked upon.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.integrate.nquad` is used. See [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad). Because the manual was not clear enough to me, I came up with the following code through trial and error.

Suppose you want to create the following function, as mentioned in the question:

$f(d,e) = \int_{-1}^1 \int_0^2 \int_0^1 (a+b+c+d+e) da db dc$

(I do not know how to display math here.)

Define the function:

```
from scipy import integrate

def f(d, e):
    def func(a, b, c, d, e):
        return a + b + c + d + e

    def bounds_a(b, c, d, e):
        return [0, 1]

    def bounds_b(c, d, e):
        return [0, 2]

    def bounds_c(d, e):
        return [-1, 1]

    return integrate.nquad(func, [bounds_a, bounds_b, bounds_c], args=(d, e,))[0]
```

Then,

```
f(1,1)
```

gives `14.0`.

Note that the order of `a,b,c,d,e` in `[bounds_a, bounds_b, bounds_c], args=(d, e,)` must be identical to that of `a,b,c,d,e` in `func(a,b,c,d,e)`. Note also that there is `,` after `e` in `args=(d,e,)`.

Generalising this to the `n` integration case should be obvious, given the `a,b,c,d,e,` structure.