# Integration of functions with optional arguments in python using scipy

Tags: python, scipy

In my Python-code, I have a function like

```
def f(x, alpha=1.):
    return (1.-x**2)**alpha
```

I want to integrate that function. One way to do so is using [scipy.integrate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/integrate.html), e.g.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
quad( f, 0, 1)
```

Now I want to vary the parameter `alpha`, calling `quad( f(alpha=2.), 0,1)` does not work, how can I realize that?

**Edit**: the values for `alpha` are varied by user-input when the code is running

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099892/how-to-evaluate-single-integrals-of-multivariate-functions-with-pythons-scipy-i; would you say this is a duplicate question?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks for the dupe

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser true, somehow missed that, thanks

Answer (score 2):

`quad` and several other functions like it has an `args` parameter which can be used to supply the additional arguments. It works if the function you're integrating has its extra arguments *after* the `x` just like you have. So you simply do

```
alpha = 2
quad(f, 0, 1, args=(alpha,))  # notice the trailing comma for the tuple
```

There are other examples in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#general-integration-quad).

Comment: ah... I was using `args`  wrong, when playing with it, thanks! Important to note is that, when using optional arguments, you have to specify **all** of them in the `args`  argument (if I understood it correctly)